# Showing value in row itself but COUNT in summary of pivot table

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have a pivot table in google sheets. My data consists of rows where columns are "carton number", "product", "pallet number" (other, non-important, columns are omitted).

I want to generate a pivot table such that I get a summary of "what is on each pallet". Basically I've put into rows the "pallet number" and "product" and then into values "carton number". The value "carton number" is shown as "COUNT".

Of course, the problem is that this pivot table doesn't show the actual "carton number", it just shows "1" per each row, but the summary row of product/pallet shows the correct carton quantity.

Hence I had to put "carton number" also into "rows". Example sheet here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xpWYeG2aJCoqmnM53ubWUroKKJT5Zy-BiipauoXUHGw/edit#gid=799560604

What I want is to have a pivot table where, in the example above, there is only 1 value of "C. N." (carton number) - showing actual carton number; and the summary row at product/pallet level shows "COUNT" of the boxes, ie. how many boxes of product are on a specific pallet.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

paste in **E1** cell and hide **C:D** columns:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"C.N."; IF(C2:C<>"", C2:C, D2:D)})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Interesting. Technically this works but this doesn't cooperate with the convenience utilities of pivot table (eg. automatically coloring rows, expanding/collapsing groups etc). Is there a way to perhaps have a calculated field with just =C.N. but the summarization is COUNT?

Comment: pivot tables are not so versatile. colapsing rows via pivot checkers should be still doable. only disadvantage is row coloring which could be created via conditional formating to mimic the pivot table

Comment: I see, that's quite unfortunate.